# mobx-react-form with dynamic fields

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

We use mobx-react-form (https://github.com/foxhound87/mobx-react-form) for our forms. One of our forms has a multi select dropdown. according to the selection, fields are added / removed from the form.
How can this be managed in mobx-react-form?

Comment: I'm the author of the package. You can find an example using react-select in the demo repo: https://github.com/foxhound87/mobx-react-form-demo/blob/master/src/components/forms/FormDynamicFieldsSelect.jsx Hope it will help.